# I have scripts for edit, view and insert, but can not place and view text with links

Tags: mysql

I have a database (id varchar and 4). I need copy/paste in the form text with a link (*„[CEEOL](http://www.ceeol.com/aspx/publicationdetails.aspx?publicationid=dd62c939-e74f-4982-ab52-92ce5272d720) nuo 2004 Central & Eastern European Academic Source nuo 2007 ([EBSCO sąrašas](http://www.ebscohost.com/titleLists/e5h-coverage.htm))“*). Then  text will need to view or edit. The text should look like the original (with aktivia link).

1. script - index.php for view data. It's work, but from database this must be links with text.

   ```
   try {
       $result = $link->query('SHOW TABLES');
       if (!$result) throw new MySQL_Exception($link->error);
      $counter = 1;
       while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
           echo "<table><caption> {$row[1]} </caption><tr>"; 
           $result1 = $link->query("SELECT 'Nr', 'Pavadinimas', 'Kitas pavadinimas', 'ISSN', 'Leidėjas', 'DB', 'Pastaba', ID FROM {$row[0]}");
           if (!$result1) throw new MySQL_Exception($link->error);
           for($i = 0; $i < $link->field_count; $i++)
           {
               $field_info = $result1->fetch_field();
               echo "<th>{$field_info->name}</th>";
           }
           echo '</tr>'; 
           $result2 = $link->query("SELECT * FROM {$row[0]} ORDER BY pavadinimas");

           while ($row1 = $result2->fetch_row()) {
               echo '<tr>';
               echo '<td>'.$counter++.'</td>';
               foreach($row1 as $_column) {
                   echo "<td>{$_column}</td>";
               }
               echo "</tr>";
           }
           echo '</table>';
       }
   }
   catch (Exception $ex) {
       echo 'Error MySQL: <b style="color:red;">'.$ex->getMessage().'</b>';
   }
   ```

   ?>

Comment: I'm sorry, this is too broad and there is too little information. This site is for asking specific, well-defined programming questions. Please show us your code so we can see what you have tried, and ask one question at a time!